# Identifying Fortran standard

Tags: code-analysis, fortran

I am looking for a program or web service that takes as input a file containing code written in Fortran, and outputs the Fortran standard used in the code (66/77/90/95/etc.)

Any price, license or operating system is fine.

Comment: "Any price, license or operating system is fine" - are you open to comissioning development of such a tool?

Comment: @Mawg no~~~~~~~

Comment: Not that I was offering to do so; I just wanted to clarify. How about some brute force Python? Just try to compile it with each of the approriate compilers and generate a report of the results? Or search for standard specific keywords?

Comment: @Mawg both would work

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: [How to identify fortran standard - '77, '90, or '95?](//stackoverflow.com/q/391897)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, it's off-topic there though, so it could be closed/deleted anytime.

Comment: You might be able to do something with [FORCHECK](http://www.forcheck.nl) - validates compliance to the Fortran standard in effect, can choose from Fortran 66, Fortran 77, Fortran 90, Fortran 95, High Performance Fortran, Fortran 2003 and Fortran 2008.

Comment: Hmm.  Would running precise lexers for different dialects discriminate well enough? F77 has a pretty limited keyword vocabulary; F90 has more keywords, etc.  I use multiple lexers to sort files of different dialects of other languages.   One could do the same with precise parsers (in the limit, this amounts to running standards-based compilers to see if they object); why isn't the latter an appropriate solution since you are completely price insensitive?